# Why does constructor initialize third variable before the second one

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
public:
    A(int val) : x(++val), z(++val), y(++val)
    {
        std::cout << "y--->" << y<< std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use code formatting and describe your problem in details please

Comment: From the standard *nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers)*. Some code analyzers and compilers will emit warnings for the member initializer list not matching the order of the members in the class for this exact reason.

Comment: A decent compiler should (with the right options enabled) [give a warning about the initialization order](https://godbolt.org/z/8H2ypa). Always make it a habit to enable almost all the warnings possible.

Comment: In above question i am initializing the x, y and z . after initializing the variable i getting the value of Y in 5 , since i have initialize it last, i was expecting value 6 .

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I don't think VS does, but I did find a feature request for it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/854649/warn-about-member-variable-initialization-order.html)

Comment: @ChrisMM I said *decent* compiler... ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude From `MSVC` (2019) with (almost) all warnings enabled: **warning C5038: data member 'A::z' will be initialized after data member 'A::y'**

Comment: So during construction initialization , precedence is not follow.

Comment: @Navneet `x(++val), z(++val), y(++val)` is not an expression, there is no notion of precedence there. Even if there was, precedence does not determine order of evaluation. And all that aside, initialization of class members happens in the order in which they are declared, not the order in the initializer list, as explained in the linked duplicate.

Comment: _"since i have initialize[d] it last"_ Nope, you haven't; you only think you have ;)

Comment: Since `val` is only used to initialize those three values, the way to write those initializers is `x(val+1), y(val+3), z(val+2)` (assuming the intention was to do the three increments in left-to-right order). You can put those in any order you like, and the initialization will be the same.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me to understand this .